# Adding an F5 Hotkey in C#

Tags: c#, hotkeys

I'm making a windows app (WinForms) and would like my application to call a method when the user presses F5 - this should work no matter what the user is doing but they must be using the program - I don't want to use global hooks - any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

Override the form's [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx) on your main form and look for F5.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey (ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    bool bHandled = false;
    // switch case is the easy way, a hash or map would be better, 
    // but more work to get set up.
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.F5:
            // do whatever
            bHandled = true;
            break;
    }
    return bHandled;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a **default** case in the switch so that and let the base class take a look at the key instead of just returning false:
`    default:
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);`

Answer (score 4):

If you have only one form that can have focus, you can set the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property of that form to `true` and handle the [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event.

The [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property will cause the form to receive all key presses, regardless which control on the form has the input focus.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it'll only work for each form you set that property for and not the global application

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `Form.KeyPreview` property, it will allow you to trap all `KeyDown`, `KeyUp` and `KeyPress` events at the form level before allowing them to be processed by individual elements.

[MSDN Form.KeyPreview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)

Comment: This only works in the case of trivial apps that are a single form and one of the forms children always has focus.  it's more like a hack that works most of the time than a solution.