# How to detect refresh button and F5 or Ctrl+F5

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, page-refresh

In codebehind of my `asp.net` page has a button and when single-click her open a `RadWindow`, don't have a problem.

The problem is when somebody `close` the radwindows, because to open is necessary double-click. I don't like this.

For me control refresh to disable the `double-click` page I use:

```
 Boolean IsPageRefresh;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["postids"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Session["postid"] = ViewState["postids"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            if (ViewState["postids"].ToString() != Session["postid"].ToString())
            {
                IsPageRefresh = true;
            }
            Session["postid"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            ViewState["postids"] = Session["postid"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

But don't work, somebody use <kbd>F5</kbd> or click in `button` the `radwindow` open again.

How can I detect to difference when use <kbd>F5</kbd> and `Click button`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect page refresh in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793588/how-to-detect-page-refresh-in-net)

Comment: @confusedandamused thanks, but I saw this post. He carry in this situation.

Comment: You can check in this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1964315/5427724](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1964315/5427724)